# Best practice for DRYing up New and Edit forms using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This should be an easy one, I'm a noob.

I have new and edit views for a model that use a partial to display a form. For the edit form I want to display a field that I do not want to display in the new form.

Should I be passing a local variable stating its in edit mode to the partial and use a condition in the partial to display the field?

Whats the best practice in this case to let the partial know what action called it?

Comment: Did some more research, would using "new_record?" in the partial be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `form_for`, you can use same template for both `new` and `edit`.

`form_for` will check if the object is persisted. If it's a new record, the action url will point to `#update`, if it's persisted, it will point to `#create`.

So, yes, your comment will work when using same template for "new" and "edit". When `obj.new_record?`, it is a edit form.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Looks like you've reversed the two. If obj.new_record? is true then it's the `new` form and will point to `#create`. If obj.persisted? is true then it's the `edit` form and will point to `#update`.

Answer (score 5):

This will only display the field for the `new` form

```
<%# app/views/something/_form.html.erb %>

<% form_for something do |form| %>

  <%# common fields ... %>

  <% if something.new_record? %>
    <%= form.text_field :foo %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

If you want it on the `edit` form, just switch `if` to `unless`

Answer (score 1):

If possible try to avoid conditionals in your view (not always possible)

_form.html.erb

```
# common fields only
# ...
```

_new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @your_model do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
      <% # render _form partial %>
  </fieldset>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Create New XXXX" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @your_model do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
      <% # render _form partial %>

      <% # render fields that only appear for edit %>
  </fieldset>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Save Changes" %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', xxxx_path %>        
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok, so this only is an option if you would like the fields to appear as appended or in the beginning? In my case they needed to be somewhere in the middle of the form inside the partial.